# Does Devarim 10:12 consist of four demands or just one?

Tags: commentaries, ekev, yirat-shamaim

Devarim 10:12

> And now, Israel, what does HaShem your G-d ask, require, or beseech
>   of you but, except, rather than… 1) to fear HaShem your G-d, 2) to
>   walk (in obedience) in all His ways (in order to imitate or present
>   Him), and 3) to love Him…. AND 4) to serve HaShem your G-d with your
>   whole heart and your whole being.

The Gemara (Berachos 34b, Megillah 25a, etc.) understands from this verse that God has one fundamental demand of us: yirat Shamayim (fear of Heaven).

I don’t understand this Gemara, because although the Gemara says we are dealing with a single entity, the verse itself seems to specify a whole list of demands. Could it be therefore that the 4 points which I summed up:
1) Yirah, 2) following Torah, 3) Ahavah and 4) Avodah, are four main-points upon which everything which is asked from us by HaShem can be hung upon, and maybe this can even be reduced to one, Yirah, because all the rest come from this one command?

Are there any commentaries that explain this?

Comment: See the intro and first chapter of mesilat yesharim for this verse

Comment: @kouty could you explain it more clear, and if possible provide a answer.

Comment: http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/kindertorah/archives/eikev69.htm: "Although the gemara says we are dealing with a single entity, the verse seems to specify a whole list of demands: The reason for
this is that fundamentally we can speak of one category, but one which
then has several components. These components break down into the two elements that I mentioned earlier: the existential, experiential
relationship to God (love and fear), and the response to God's
commands (keeping His mitzvot).

Comment: The latter takes place both in broader
terms (“walking in all His paths and serving Him”) and in the specific
details of Halakha (“to keep the Lord’s commandments and laws, which I
enjoin upon you today”).

Comment: Rav Shimshon Rafael Hirsch zt"l comments that 'going in all Hashem's ways and loving Him' are the result of yiras shomayim. Fear of Hashem leads a person to walk in His ways. He benefits and grows from this, as the verse states, '(The Torah's) ways are ways of pleasantness' (Mishlei 3:17). They fill a person's heart with richness and satisfaction. This brings him to love the One Who guides him along the beautiful path." And the Zohar states (vol 6): Trough fear, he will merit it all

Comment: Fear of Hashem leads to walking in his ways, loving him, and serving him with all. The only thing we need to do is learn to fear.
יִרְאַת יְהוָה רֵאשִׁית דָּעַת

Comment: Which Gemara are you referencing? How do you know that the Gemara says this?

Comment: @mevaqesh in addition to Dov F: All is in the hands of Heaven except the fear of Heaven

Comment: @Levi `The gemara understands from this verse` Which Gemara?

Comment: I got it from quotes of other Rabbi's:By His Light: 'Character and Values in the Service of G-d' by Rabbi Reuven, Ziegler,Aharon Lichtenstein

Comment: Maybe I should quote a Rabbi who said the same thing and the Gemara: 1. By His Light: 'Character and Values in the Service of G-d' by Rabbi Reuven, Ziegler,Aharon Lichtenstein. 2. Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai stated: God has nothing [of man’s deeds] in His treasury except a store of the fear of heaven” (Berachot 33b). 3 "When all has been considered: Fear God and [trough this fear] keep His commandments for this is the whole of man” (Kohelet 12:13). Nice adittion from Rashi: There are two paths placed before a man, and he has to choose fear of G-d for himself. (Rashi).

Comment: @ mevaqesh Should I add it in?

Comment: This is a great question, one I’ve wondered on several occasions. I’m actually surprised I hadn’t seen it before. I added in where the Gemara makes this comment for you.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER BY LEVI:

Rav Shimshon Rafael Hirsch zt"l comments that 'going in all Hashem's ways and loving Him' are the result of yiras shomayim. Fear of Hashem leads a person to walk in His ways. He benefits and grows from this, as the verse states, '(The Torah's) ways are ways of pleasantness' (Mishlei 3:17). They fill a person's heart with richness and satisfaction. This brings him to love the One Who guides him along the beautiful path." And the Zohar states (vol 6): Through fear, he will merit it all – Levi